# How to getDate with yyyy-MM-dd format

Tags: java, date

How can I get the current date of the system with this format `yyyy-MM-dd`

I want this

```
SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = new Date();
String strDate = formatDate.format(now);
return strDate;
```

but returning a `Date` instead of a `String`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: If that's the case, can I parse my String to Date?

Answer (score 7):

> How can i get the current date of the system with this format yyyy-MM-dd but returns Date instead of String.

You can't. There's no such thing as "a `Date` with a format" any more than there's the concept of "an `int` with a format". A `Date` value is *just* a point in time, with no associated text format, calendar system or time zone.

Using `new Date()` will get you a `Date` object representing the current instant in time, and nothing else. How you use that is up to you - but if you return it from a method then there is no associated date (as the date will vary by time zone), no format etc - it's up to the calling code to use it appropriately.

You might want to consider using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) which at least has a `LocalDate` type - although you still need to consider which time zone you want to use when you think about "the current date". (And there's still no formatting information associated with the value.)

EDIT: To answer your update, you can just use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse - but it's not clear where your string has come from to start with. This sounds like the *opposite* requirement from the rest of your question.

Comment: best possible answer , you rock sir

Comment: If that's the case, can I parse my String to Date?

Comment: @sftdev: Using `SimpleDateFormat` - but I thought you were *starting* with a `Date`. Your requirements are *very* unclear at this point.

Answer (score 1):

since you cant change `Date` format build your own CustomDate, it is just a representation of time.

Answer (score 0):

on the method which recieves the date as a string 
use another simpledateformatter
and convert the string into date by using

```
simpledateformatter.parse(strDate);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this .!!

```
String formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format( yourDate);
```